# Python send keystrokes to exe file

Tags: python

I need to send keystrokes to an exe using python. I can run the exe using python from subprocess as

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('myfile.exe',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but how can I keep the connection and keep sending keys. I don't want to read back from the exe just to send some keystrokes any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
>   The optional input argument should be data to be sent to the child
>   process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child. If streams
>   were opened in text mode, input must be a string. Otherwise, it must
>   be bytes.
>
> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data
>   will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.